# Pentaho/Kettle: Table input stops at aroound 255 thousand rows versus MSSQL Express

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, kettle

I am running a "Table Input" against a table on MSSQL Express, to a Dummy step. The table has got over 600 thousand rows and about 35 columns.
The table input stops at around 255 thousand rows, i.e. Status is still "running" but not another single one row is written.
Anyone who knows a solution to that? Would appreciate that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How big is the table (in gigabytes) at the point that the insert stalls out? SQL Server Express caps database size at 10GB.

Comment: Tried the same with a copy of the aforementioned table. Copy does NOT have any key neither an index. Worked properly!

Comment: Table has got a size of around 255 thousand MEGAbytes